# Non existence of a iterated integral

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let

f(x,y)=1 if x is rational

f(x,y)=2*y otherwise

The problem is:

Does the following iterated integral exist?

∫    (∫ f(x,y) dx )   dy

with x∈[0,1], y∈[0,1]

I know that the integral with respect to x is similar to the integral of the Dirichlet  function (which is not integrable)... But how can I prove in this case, in which I have a double variable function?

Any help would be fantastic...

Comment: I assume you're working with Riemann integral?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look at the upper and lower integrals when you restrict to $x \geq 1/2,y \geq 1/2$.